# Aggregating a raster to fit a polygon grid

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, polygon

I am working at the scale of 10 square km grid cells for the UK, and have a polygon layer of the Ordnance Survey 10k grid cells in ArcGIS.

I have another layer of the human footprint index, also for the entire UK, that I am using to stratify my data.

However, the resolution of this human footprint index is much greater than that of the 10k grid cells, so I want to aggregate the cells, such that I have a human footprint index value for each 10 sqkm cell.

When I try to do this, however, the squares and grid do not line up - as can be seen in the pictures.

They are in the same projection.

Is there any way to aggregate a layer to the confines of a polygon grid?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Images here:

[image: Before aggregation]
[image: After aggregation]

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @whuber, please try **[Zonal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000)** which will require you to use a **Spatial Analyst** license.